# get the last value of table

Tags: erlang

I have a table person which has this record :

```
-record(person, {id, firstname, lastname, address}).
```

I want to develop a function which will retreive the last id of this table

I try with this function :

```
get_userId() ->
    Q = qlc:q([{X#person.id} || X <- mnesia:table(person)
                ]),
    case do(Q) of
        [{H}] ->
            {ok, H};
        [] ->
            {error, notfound}
    end.
```

And I do the test with this code

```
test()->
    case get_userId() of
         {ok, H}->io:format("~s~n",[H]);

         [] ->
            {error, notfound}
     end.
```

but I have error when I make the test

```
2> model:test().
** exception error: no case clause matching [{238},
                                             {82},
                                             {76},
                                             {257},
                                             {141},
                                             {2},
                                             {315},
                                             {336},
                                             {275},
                                             {88},
                                             {326},
                                             {211},
                                             {81},
                                             {333},
                                             {351},
                                             {214},
                                             {64},
                                             {265},
                                             {210},
                                             {90},
                                             {302},
                                             {98},
                                             {212},
                                             {197},
                                             {194},
                                             {132},
                                             {226},
                                             {3},
                                             {...}|...]
     in function  model:get_userId/0
     in call from model:test/0
```

Comment: I want the equivalent of this sql systax :  SELECT id FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value returned from `do(Q)` is a list containing many elements. You see them listed in the error report. However patterns which you match this value against only will match a list with **one** element, `[{H}]`, the list with no elements, the empty list `[]`. Therefore you get a `case_clause` error as none of the clauses match.